# Сумма цифр шестнадцатеричного числа

Tags: python, алгоритм, числа, теория-чисел

Найти однозначное число которое получается вычислением суммы цифр шестнадцатеричного числа(беззнаковое) n (повторно).

Пример:

```
40820A2 -> 4 + 0 + 8 + 2 + 0 + A + 2 = 1A;
1A -> 1 + A = B
```

Т.е. происходит преобразование

```
40820A2 -> B
```

Comment: А где собственно вопрос и собственная попытка решения?

Comment: @MaxU, У меня решение есть. Мне интересно как сообщество решит эту задачу.

Comment: Пожалуйста возьмите на заметку, на данном ресурсе выработан порядок - сначало вы в вопросе, потом сообщество в ответах, но никак не наоборот.

Comment: @0xdb, изъясняйтесь понятнее. Наоборот - это сообщество в вопросах, а я в ответе. Правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ы?

```
print(hex(int(input(),16)%15))
```

С учетом замечания @Danis

```
r = int(input(),16)%15 
print(hex(r if r > 0 else 15))
```

Да, еще если исходное значение 0 - то 0...

Comment: ... и другие приключения Шурика ))

Comment: Самое сложное было найти, как в Python считать 16-ричное число и как его вывести :)

Comment: отличный ответ, но если на вход подать число кратное 15, то будет неверный результат

Comment: @Danis принимается. Полез искать в Интернете, как это на Python'е написать :)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Да я понимаю, просто язык знаю на уровне чайника...

Comment: да, можно так написать `i = int(input(), 16)
print(hex((i - 1) % 15 + 1) if i else 0)`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Спасибо за подсказку :)

Comment: вместо `r if r > 0 else 15` можно написать `r if r else 15`

Comment: @Danis И вам тоже. Люди, кто тут гуру в Python - исправьте ответ, так будет проще :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def fun(num):
    return num if len(num) < 2 else fun(hex(sum(int(c, 16) for c in num))[2:])
```

тесты:

```
In [125]: fun("40820A2")
Out[125]: 'b'

In [126]: fun("1234ae678d9f")
Out[126]: '2'
```

Comment: возможно есть решение проще .)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, почти всегда есть решение проще)